# Access 2007 Update Query with multiple criterias on single column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Col1 . . . . .Col2
    AA
    BB
    CC
    AA
    BB
    CC

I need to update Col2, keeping in mind following conditions.

```
If Col1 = AA, then Col2 = A 
If Col1 = BB, then Col2 = B
If Col1 = CC, then Col2 = C
```

I went through Build option and in functions, could see, IIF, Switch, and Choose, but can't understand how can I use them, for constructing a query, with multiple criteria.

Thanks for time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Col2=
(
    Switch 
    ( 
        Col1 = 'AA', 'B', 
        Col1 = 'BB', 'B', 
        Col1 = 'CC', 'C',
        true,'Unknowed'
    )
)
```

Reference:

- [MS ACCESS: SWITCH FUNCTION](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php)